# Rounded corner without image on imageview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have developed one rounded example using image on imageview.

i am used below code:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:background="@drawable/imagestyle"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

This is imagestyle.xml in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00000000" /> 
    <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> 
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"  android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" /> 
    <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Here i got the o/p like below:

[image]

But i wish to need the same o/p without using image.
For eg:i mustn't use this line android:src="@drawable/arrow" and create the below image via xml code in imagestyle.xml.

How can i do.please help me.

**EDIT:**

now i have to changed my above code:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/imagestyle"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

This is **imagestyle**.xml in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#DC143C" /> 
    <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> 
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" /> 
    <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
    <gradient android:startColor="#18d7e5"
        android:centerColor="#16cedb"
        android:endColor="#09adb9"
        android:angle="270" />
    <size android:width="20px" android:height="20px" />
</shape>
```

Now i have created rounded shape without using image and also only change the
imagestyle.xml file.

now i got the o/p like below image:

[image]

How is add the triangle shape in above image like my first image.please help me.

Comment: have you looked at LayerListDrawables?

Comment: ya i saw the above concepts.here i wish to create the arrow without using that arrow image anyplace.create the arrow using xml code.like css triangle image without using image.div.arrow-up {
  width:0px; 
  height:0px; 
  border-left:5px solid transparent;  /* left arrow slant */
  border-right:5px solid transparent; /* right arrow slant */
  border-bottom:5px solid #2f2f2f; /* bottom, add background color here */
  font-size:0px;
  line-height:0px;
}    like android how can we develop without image and create arrow via xml code